# php ldap_search for sub groups resulting in all users listed

Tags: php, ldap, ldap-query

I am doing a php ldap_search where i am looking for any sub groups from a parent group. I pick the dn and cn from the search result  and then later on show the sub groups

```
$search= ldap_search(cn=parent-group,cn=groups,dc=company,dc=net, "cn=*")
$info = ldap_get_entries($search);
                        
                        for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++) {
                            $dn=$info[$i]["dn"];
                            $group_cn= $info[$i]["cn"][0];
                            array_push($group_array, "$group_cn : $dn"); 
foreach($group_array as $group){
echo $group;
}
```

This will result in output like this:

```
group1 : cn=group1,cn=parent-group,cn=groups,dc=company,dc=net
group2 : cn=group2,cn=parent-group,cn=groups,dc=company,dc=net
```

This is giving me the sub groups as im looking for them, my problem is the search is also getting results for users (uniqueMembers) and when one of the sub groups is very big the search takes far to long.

I have tried changing the search filter to be "dn:*" and "cn=groups*" but both options dont seem to be valid filters.

How else can i change my search so it doesnt list the uniqueMembers in the out put.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the filter so that the search returns only group entries, and also request only the necessary attributes :

```php
$filter = 'objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames';
$attr = ['dn', 'cn'];

$search = ldap_search($base, $filter, $attr);
```

Comment: Ahh amazing i think this is exactly what i need. Im just testing it but will mark as accepted answer once im done.